# makefile:45: *** missing separator. Stop

Tags: makefile

I've checked out and read all of the answers which I probably should. I've tried adding a tab and checking for spaces. However, I still get errors while running `make`.

Below is my working tree:

```
$tree 

.
├── bin
├── cu
│   └── kernel_gpu.cu
├── inc
│   └── kernel.h
├── Makefile
├── obj
│   ├── kernel_gpu.o
│   └── main.o
└── src
    ├── kernel.cxx
    └── main.cxx
```

I try to use `wildcard` and `patsubst` to make my `Makefile` look good.
Here is my `Makefile`:

```
DIR_INC = ./inc
DIR_SRC = ./src
DIR_CU  = ./cu
DIR_OBJ = ./obj
DIR_BIN = ./bin


SRC = $(wildcard ${DIR_SRC}/*.cxx)
SRC_CU = $(wildcard ${DIR_CU}/*.cu) 
OBJ = $(patsubst %.cxx,${DIR_OBJ}/%.o,$(notdir ${SRC})) 
CUOBJ = $(patsubst %.cu,${DIR_OBJ}/%.o,$(notdir ${SRC_CU})) 
BIN_TARGET = ${DIR_BIN}/${TARGET}

TARGET = test 

CXX=g++
CU=nvcc

CUDA_INSTALL_PATH= /usr/local/cuda
CUDAFLAGS= -O2 -I. -I$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/include -I ${DIR_INC}
LDFLAGS= -L$(CUDA_INSTALL_PATH)/lib64 -lcudart


${OBJ}:${SRC}
    $(CXX) $(CUDAFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(CUOBJ):$(SRC_CU)
    $(CU) $(CUDAFLAGS) -o $@ -c $<

${BIN_TARGET}:${DIR_OBJ}/%.o
    $(CXX) $< -o $@ ${LDFLAGS}

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    find ${DIR_OBJ} -name *.o -exec rm -rf {} \;
```

I always get the same error message when typing `make` in my shell:

```
$ make
Makefile:45: *** missing separator.  Stop.
```

Line 45 is:

```
44 ${OBJ}:${SRC}
45     $(CXX) $(CUDAFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

I echoed the variable `${OBJ}` and `${SRC}` and the result is shown as:

```
./src/main.cxx ./src/kernel.cxx
./obj/main.o ./obj/kernel.o
```

Comment: Line 45 must start with a TAB character.

Comment: Please paste in the output of `cat -e -t -v Makefile` so that we can verify that the tabs are correct.

Comment: sorry! checked! you are right, thank you so much.

Comment: *This aspect of the syntax of makefiles is often subject to criticism; it has been described [...] as "one of the worst design botches in the history of Unix"* [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Make_(software)#Rules)

Comment: If you're willing to be limited to GNU make 4.0 and above, you can use `.RECIPEPREFIX` to avoid this issue: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Special-Variables.html#index-_002eRECIPEPREFIX-_0028change-the-recipe-prefix-character_0029

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace those four spaces with a hard tab.

If you're using some sort of editor that replaces hard tabs with spaces, you'll need to disable that or use a different editor.

Comment: solved, thank you so much.

Comment: @ShangKe Please upvote the answer and accept it by clicking the gray checkmark if it helped you.